# Find Minimal Type

Tags: types, type-theory

The following two types are equivalent:

```
unit -> ([record(fn: unit -> fix)]  as fix)       (A)
[unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix                 (B)
```

however neither can be obtained from the other by unrolling or substitutions, nor is there any more general type from which they can be derived in this manner (AFAICS). Clearly the second type is minimal (because it is recursive). Given such a type, is there an algorithm for minimisation? Clearly, each CAN be derived from the other, since they unify using tracing.

These types arose when a function contained in a record returns a value of the same type as the record. My problem is that my compiler is generating two distinct incompatible representation in the target language.

In general, given any cycle, we can derive a type by picking a starting point, following the circle around partly, picking a fixpoint, and then running all the way around to the fixpoint again.

Two types with distinct starting points are distinct, but they can be made equal by backtracking one to the starting point of the other. Here is a picture:

```
A: function <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+
     unit                    |
     record  <---------+     | 
       field           |     |
         "fn"          |     |
B:       function >>>> | >>>>+ B^
           unit        |
           record -----+ A^
```

Comment: If this problem turns out to be a form of equivalence under beta-reduction, it may very well be undecidable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the first complete discussion of the problem of checking equalities of recursive type is Roberto Amadio and Luca Cardelli's 1991 [Subtyping recursive types](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/SRT.pdf). In particular, they point out that just considering finite unfoldings is not enough to decide equality between recursive type (see remark at the beginning of page 13, with example that we would now write `mu a. t -> t -> a` and `mu a. t -> a`: the "semantic equalities" (equalities of infinite unfoldings) are richer than the equalities derivable from just unfolding. They then go on to propose an algorithm to check the semantic equality. This algorithm has been refined a lot since, with various more efficient versions proposed, and an understanding that co-induction is the right way to reason about this problem (see for example [Subtyping Recursive Types, Revealed](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1157&context=cis_papers), Vladimir Gapeyev, Michael Y. Levin, Benjamin Pierce, 2000).

The way the algorithm of Amadio and Cardelli works is by comparing the pair of types directly (instead of trying to normalize the types and check for equality), and remember (in the usual co-inductive fashion) the equalities that they are "currently trying to prove" in a set of assumptions. If, after going under some type constructors, you end back on one of these assumptions, you can tie the proof knot and claim the types are equal. On your example that would go as:

```
unit -> ([record(fn: unit -> fix)]  as fix)
=?= (1)
[unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix 

unfold the second type

unit -> ([record(fn: unit -> fix)]  as fix)
=?= (2)
unit -> record(fn: [unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix)

peel the common (unit ->) part.

[record(fn: unit -> fix)]  as fix
=?= (3)
record(fn: [unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix)

unfold the first type

record(fn: unit -> [record(fn: unit -> fix)]  as fix)
=?= (4)
record(fn: [unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix)

peel the common record(fn : ) part

unit -> [record(fn: unit -> fix)] as fix
=?= (1)
[unit -> record(fn: fix)]  as fix

(5) is the same as the previously-seen equation (2), so the types are
equal by assumption.
```

You ask a different question: not how to decide equalities between recursive types, but whether there exists a "canonical" representation of a recursive type such as two equivalent recursive types have the same canonical representation -- reached, in your proposition, by un-doing the un-wrapping operation, if I understand correctly. (Note that the Amadio and Cardelli paper mentions "canonical representations", but they use the word for a different notion that is not, in fact, canonical in the sense above.)

I don't understand the details of your proposition, but I am not a priori convinced that such a canonical representation exists. For a given *pair* of types, it is possible to check their equivalence, and if they indeed are equivalent I think you can read back the equivalence proof as a series of transformation (possibly related to your `unwrap` operation) that turns them both in the same "smaller common multiple" representation. But the "smaller common multiple" (or, if you wish, most general unifier) is given for a pair of types; a given type will have infinitely many distinct "common multiple" when comparing it to other types. Of course your algorithm is not producing a canonical representation by unfolding/unwrapping the type, but by the converse operation of folding/wrapping it, so it might still work.

Do you really need this canonical representation, or are you looking for an algorithm to compute equality of recursive types?

Comment: I would *like* to have a canonical representation, because for each type used in a Felix program, my compiler generates a C++ type. Typically this will be a C++ struct or pointer thereto. If two equivalent types have different representations in the compiler, distinct, incompatible, C++ types will be generated, and the generated C++ will not type check. The Felix compiler itself uses the Cardelli unification algorithm, and the related type equivalence check.

Comment: I have just fixed the compiler, by changing the type registry from a hashtable mapping each used type to a unique integer (so as to generate distinct C++ types), to a list of pairs. Now, instead of checking the hashtable to see if the type is already registered, I scan the whole list of already registered types and compare with the type equivalence algorithm. In other words I just pick the first presented of a set of equivalent types as the canonical representative. Not happy going from O(1) to O(n), nor does this method seem elegant (but it fixed my test case!).

Comment: Subtyping Recursive Types, Revealed: link (thanks, although Felix doesn't do any subtyping ..): http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1157&context=cis_papers

Answer (score 0):

On further thought I think I have an partial answer. First the visual picture: a piece of string with coloured segments representing combinators and the tail of which is tied to the string to with a knot, to form a directed loop at the bottom. (The knot of course is the fixpoint and the point it attaches to is the binding point ...:)

The algorithm for that path is to roll the loop up one level to see if the tail segment has the same colour as the tail of the linear part before the knot. If so, try again until you have a loop or the match fails.

In terms of the type terms, run from the root down to each leaf. If you pass a fixpoint binder and end in a fixpoint, try to match the term enclosing the fixpoint with the term enclosing the fixpoint binder. If they match, replace the term containing the fixpoint with the fixpoint, and shift the fixpoint binder up the path one level. Repeat.

Repeat for every path. The result is NOT minimal because it does not handle a recursive term which is unfolded once, however the result can then be refolded to remove unfolds. So roughly two recursive descents.

However the complexity is worse. This is because for, say, a binary combinator, where we travel down the left path, the "colour" of the combinator is the kind of combinator PLUS the whole right hand subtree. And we cannot simply compare the right hand paths, since they may not yet be minimised, instead we have to use a structural comparison with tracing. Ouch.

Edit: Here is my fold routine in Ocaml, it refolds the unfold of a recursive term. The encoding uses implicit fixpoint binders, the fix term simply records the (negative of the) number of levels up to go, this eliminates the need for mu variables.

```
let fold t =
  let rec aux trail depth t' =
    let ax t = aux ((depth,t')::trail) (depth+1) t in
    match t' with
    | BTYP_record (ls) -> List.iter (fun (s,t) -> ax t) ls
    | BTYP_function (a,b) -> ax a; ax b
    | BTYP_fix (0,_) -> ()
    | BTYP_fix (i,_) ->
      let k = depth + i in
      begin try
        let t'' = List.assoc k trail in
        if type_eq t'' t then raise (Found t'')
      with Not_found -> ()
      end
  in
    try aux [] 0 t; t
    with Found t -> t

let minimise bsym_table counter t =
  fold (map ~f_btype:fold  t)
```

Minimise doesn't work. The idea is to roll up the trail in the fix point handler, by comparing the terms one up the trail, however this cannot be done in the fold routine as it is written.